# How to really install PHP with NGINX?

Tags: 18.04, php, nginx

After all basic steps of `apt` install NGINX and PHP on my local (not a server) fresh UBUNTU 18 LTS,   localhost is good but basic `phpinfo.php` script not works: **"502 Bad Gateway"**

---

I need all simple and plug-and-play.. Changed `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` to

```
# Default server configuration
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name _;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               include fastcgi_params;
        }
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Versions:

- PHP 7.2
- nginx 1.14

Permissions:

- `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www; sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www`
- (tested `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` but no error  changes)

---

`sudo tail /var/log/nginx/error.log`  shows

*... *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost"*

Comment: Check if `php-fpm` creates a socket at location `/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock` and check if socket is enabled in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` file. The line `listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock` should be UNcommented.

Comment: Hi @MichalPrzybylowicz, thanks the suggestion (I see only later sorry).  Well, see solution, we not need to change  `etc/php/7.*/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`, it was only a NGINX-script (sites-available) error (at script we can call "php7.2" socket instead "php7.0")

Answer (score 1):

`sudo tail /var/log/nginx/error.log`  shows  *".. unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock..."*, so we think "... php7.0, is it?".

The standard NGINX suggest to use (uncomment) `fastcgi_pass`... that is very sensitive to the version. Need a comment there (!). But [this solution is not ideal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23729043/287948), need to control the PHP port (more configs - is it?)...

So changing the `7.0` of the file `sites-available/default`, at line `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;` to `7.2`, solved the problem.

Comment: Known issue in 18.04's packages, but not SRU-fixable currently on its own.  Fixed in later package versions.